# Mongoid::Errors::NoParent when creating embedded document in mongodb with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am learning MongoId. I got No Parent Error when testing 1-n embeded documents.
Here are the Model:

```
class Cargo
   include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :price, type: Float
  embeds_many :imgs
 end
class Img
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :url, type:String
  embedded_in  :cargo
end
```

All controller stayed as scaffold default.

a partial template imgs/_formofmg.html.erb was created for img.

```
<%= form_for(img) do |f| %>
    <% if img.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(img.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this img from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% img.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :url %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :url%>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

In cargos/show.html.erb I render this template:

```
<%= render :partial => "imgs/formofimg",:locals => {:img=> @cargo.imgs.build()} %>
```

When this template was submitted to create a img embedded in Cargo, An error was throw:

```
Mongoid::Errors::NoParent in ImgsController#create
Problem: Cannot persist embedded document Img without a parent document. Summary: If the document is embedded, in order to be persisted it must always have a reference to its parent document. This is most likely caused by either calling Img.create or Img.create! without setting the parent document as an attribute. Resolution: Ensure that you've set the parent relation if instantiating the embedded document direcly, or always create new embedded documents via the parent relation.

Extracted source (around line #30):

respond_to do |format|
if @img.save
format.html { redirect_to @img, notice: 'Img was successfully created.' }
format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @img }
else

Rails.root: /home/fwoods/dev/prj/mongoid_spec
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/imgs_controller.rb:30:in `block in create'
app/controllers/imgs_controller.rb:29:in `create'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"HKTX33u28NrChiUJ02O+yCnbJOA1IFuSPQphCAPT4LA=",
 "img"=>{"url"=>"qweqwe"},
 "commit"=>"Create Img"}
```

But when I checked the database in rails console, all imgs were created with empty url attribute.

```
irb(main):009:0> Cargo.first().imgs
D, [2014-03-09T16:31:29.014384 #10070] DEBUG -- :   MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=mongoid_spec_development collection=cargos selector={"$query"=>{}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.8659ms
=> [#<Img _id: 5319d7f97562751fab020000, url: nil>, #<Img _id: 5319dac77562751fab030000, url: nil>, #<Img _id: 5319dbc57562751fab040000, url: nil>, #<Img _id: 5319dce07562751fab050000, url: nil>, #<Img _id: 5319dd0e7562751fab060000, url: nil>, #<Img _id: 5319dd277562751fab070000, url: nil>, #<Img _id: 531c26aa7562752756000000, url: "example">]
```

Noted that the last img "example" was created by irb , not the web app.

Is it a wrong parameter setting when rendering the partial template?

Comment: `form_for(img)` doesn't make sense when `img` is an embedded document nor does `@img.save`. Embedded documents exist only with respect to their parents (they're just Hashes inside another Hash after all) so you can only work with them by going through their parent. You don't edit an Img, you edit the Cargo.

Comment: please add the controller code for creating images and the permit params in that request.